# Javascript function compiling?

Tags: javascript, function

I have noticed that when coding in javascript, it doesn't matter if i declare the function before or after i call it. In other languages it will cause an exception, but when running javascript in chrome it works just fine. Is that only in chrome, or is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is function hoisting in action: http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting

Comment: Basically, setting it as a variable makes the function only work after the variable is set, and declaring it with the function keyword directly makes it accessible from anywhere, anytime.